# Slow cors preflight OPTIONS Request in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-chrome, cors

I'm struggling with a freaky problem, that only occurs in Chrome.

My angular SPA communicates with a node.js-Backend on a different subdomain (api.domain.com). To get this working, i use [the cors npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Everything works fine, except the download-time of OPTIONS preflight in Chrome.

[Screenshot of OPTIONS slower than PUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1yqi.png)
[The timing tab shows that most time is spent by downloading content, but there is no Content-Body in my response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N80ii.png)

This timing only occurs in Chrome. Firefox, IE, Edge and Opera are not affected.

I use node.js with express and cors inside docker containers. Frontend is an angular 1 SPA.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Super slow preflight OPTIONS in Chrome only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218440/super-slow-preflight-options-in-chrome-only)

Answer (score 2):

I've been seeking to debug this and it does appear to be a chrome bug as we were experiencing the same issue.

For reference, I've filed a bug report to chromium here: [CORS pre-flight and subsequent requests are very slow only on Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=803580)

I'm adding this here to help stop any more developers spending half a day investigating it ;) Will update as we here more from Chromium.

Overview of bug report follows:

**UserAgent:**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36`

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Have app.domain.com
2. List item
3. Have api.domain.com
4. Enable CORS on API to enable access
5. Check responses in DevTools, see OPTIONS and GET requests are taking up to 300ms+

**What is the expected behavior?**

Response timings should be accurate.

**What went wrong?**

We are using Go microservices and noticed a big disparity in the time taken between browsers - chrome being the slowest up to a magnitude of 100x.

when we have checked the timings from the backend, responses take at most 10ms, with most being sub 1ms. When checking the timing under devtools the same responses were coming in at ~100ms~1s.

**Did this work before?**

N/A

Chrome version: 63.0.3239.132  Channel: stable
OS Version: 10.0
Flash Version:

In Firefox (and any other browser), the exact same requests return in ~1-20ms as expected.

In trying to diagnose further, we used Telerik's Fiddler to check the actual network response times and confirmed that they were being sent and received by Chrome within our expected timings. The only conclusion we could come to is that something internal to Chrome is slowing the processing of these requests down.

We tried all permutations of `chrome://flags#out-of-blink-cors` and `chrome://flags#enable-site-per-process`, which are the two options which we spotted which seem vaguely relevant.  Nothing seemed to help.

We have also found many Stack Overflow articles about a similar issues that make mention of it being a Chrome bug, but I haven't been able to find it reported here:

- [Super slow preflight OPTIONS in Chrome only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218440/super-slow-preflight-options-in-chrome-only?rq=1)
- https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/147
- [Slow cors preflight OPTIONS Request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206992/slow-cors-preflight-options-request-in-chrome)

We've just tested Chrome on MacOS and it doesn't appear to be an issue - so may be limited to Windows.

Chrome:
[image: optionsChrome]
[image: getChrome]

Edge:
[image: optionsEdge]
[image: getEdge]

Firefox:
[image: optionsFirefox]
[image: getFirefox]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express you can try this hack and write a middleware function with all your CORS stuff, check if the request is a preflight and just return 200. Hope this fixes it for you. But then again I don't use this dependency and its weird that it only occurs in chrome.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {    //CORS
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, x-access-token, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 
Unfortunately, it doesn't fix my problem :( Do you have another idea?

Comment: It seems to be a chrome bug. assuming your production app will be running on the same server as your API, you could get rid of CORS by proxying your request through a small server on your domain. 
https://blog.javascripting.com/2015/01/17/dont-hassle-with-cors/