# Resource timing doesn't add up in Chrome / Edge dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, chromium

What could be the reason that the timing of a resource loading doesn't add up?

As can be seen in the screenshot below, all steps are in the single digit ms, but total is 322.49.

[image: Screenshot 1]

The waterfall chart also shows an empty gap
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I checked the Network section in the dev tools and I found that it works fine in Chrome and Edge, something like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOIrn.png), have you tried clearing the browser cache or resetting the dev tools? And does this issue occur on a specific site?

Comment: The network section works fine most of the time for me, this particular one is on a `localhost:8000` address. The `disable cache` option is already checked. It was a recurring issue for all `fetch` and `script` resource types, where there's a big gap between DNS Lookup and Initial Connection as shown in screenshot above.

Comment: Found another SO question that points to this being a `localhost` specific issue. No answer on what the gap is though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762402/ajax-query-weird-delay-between-dns-lookup-and-initial-connection-on-chrome-but-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue from making queries to `localhost`. [Related SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762402/ajax-query-weird-delay-between-dns-lookup-and-initial-connection-on-chrome-but-n)